# Interpolate Method Definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This method does not have a description on the APIdock. I know `instance_exec` in Ruby is similar to the `this` binding mechanism in JavaScript.

```
def interpolate(sql, record = nil)
    if sql.respond_to?(:to_proc)
      owner.instance_exec(record, &sql)
    else
      sql
    end
  end
```

Could someone briefly describe it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the check for `respond_to?(:to_proc)` is necessary to make sure `sql` might be converted to lambda (by ampersand `&` to be passed to `instance_exec`. To simplify things, one might treat `sql` here as being a lambda already:

```
def interpolate(sql, record = nil) # assume sql is lambda
  owner.instance_exec(record, &sql)
end
```

As by documentation on [`instance_exec`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_exec):

> Executes the given block within the context of the receiver...

That said, lambda will be executed as it was the ordinal code, placed somewhere inside instance method of the receiver.

```
class Owner
  def initialize
    @records = [:zero, :one, :two]
  end
end

record_by_index = ->(idx) { @records[idx] }
Owner.new.instance_exec 1, &record_by_index #⇒ :one
```

The code above is *[more or less]* an equivalent to:

```
class Owner
  def initialize
    @records = [:zero, :one, :two]
  end
  def record_by_index idx
    @records[idx]
  end 
end

Owner.new.record_by_index(1) #⇒ :one
```

The actual parameters of call to `instance_exec` will be passed to the codeblock. In the context of `Owner`’s instance we have an access to instance variables, private methods, etc. Hope it helps.